# Publish files to a particular folder in VSTS

Tags: build, continuous-integration, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using VSTS tasks for Exporting MS Dynamics CRM Solutions which retrieves the named solution from a CRM instance. That's running properly and afterwards I use a publish Artifact task to push the exported zip files into a folder called Solution Folder

That seems to be running and the log displays that as much:
[Publish Artifact log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kLu8.png)
And exported solutions appear in the artifacts tab on the build itself but not in the folder that was specified in the repo
[VSTS Published artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlvqo.png)
Is this the right way to do it and should the exported files be present in the folder that I specified or would there be a way to point to the drop folder so I could use other tasks to further work with the solution files?

Comment: It looks like your artifacts are publishing just fine. What is the  _folder that was specified in the repo_ that you talk about? Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: @HenrikH sorry for the late reply. The folder specified is the one shown in the post image 'VSTS Published artifacts'. [Can't upload images here or add more links in the post.]

I've set output path and the publish task's 'Path to Publish' to the folder from the repo, by using a process variable to indicate the folder and by choosing the folder from the field's drop down list which allows me to navigate to the folder in question from the repo.

Now when I go to the build, I can see the artifact is called SolutionsFolder and the files are there just not in the repo under the code.

Comment: Artifacts are artifacts. They are not checked into source control. Everything appears to be as expected, in my view.

Comment: Your next step would be to use the artifacts from a Release to import the solution into your target CRM environments

Comment: That would be acceptable, however the main goal of this exercise is to capture the solution(s) and use solutionpackager to expand the solution and have it checked into source control. The fact that the intended folder appears in the artifacts list and also shows one of the files I initially checked in with the project i.e. inflater.txt but fails to appear in the repo is perturbing. However, your point about using the artifacts to import into a target CRM has given me idea. Thanks for the input .I'm not currently working on this due to other obligations but will come back with findings.

Comment: Yes, that is not uncommon. I would definitely recommend checking out Wael Hamze's xrm-ci-framework. His deploy process sounds quite similar to what you are aiming for: https://github.com/WaelHamze/xrm-ci-framework/wiki

Comment: Thanks, one of the tasks is from his framework, I just wanted to setup a rudimentary system to pull down solutions and store to repo as primer. The latest version is missing the solutionpackager task but hoping to mock it up myself.